# Changing the symbol in d3's GeoPaths MultiPoints

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

When I render latitude/longitude points (`my_coords`) on my globe with:

```
svg.append("path")
      .datum({type: "MultiPoint", coordinates: my_coords})
      .attr("class", "points")
      .attr("d", path);
```

I get circles. I can change the color with CSS, but how can I change the symbol from circles to triangles? I've tried:

```
svg.append("path")
  .datum({type: "MultiPoint", coordinates: my_coords})
    .attr("class", "point")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"));
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: How is `path` defined?

Comment: `var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);` and `var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()` with some further manipulations for size and orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    //define triangle
var arc = d3.svg.symbol().type('triangle-up');
    // put a triangle on every city

svg.selectAll(".tripath")
    .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.places).features)
 .enter().append("path")
    .attr('d',arc)
.attr("transform", function(d) {
return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; });
```

Here the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/6d3ansfn/

Here the SVG Shape reference from Mike's github: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#symbol

Example code is from Mike: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

If you has a .tsv file width coordinates, use this:

```
svg.selectAll(".tripath")
      .data( my_coords)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr('d',arc)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + projection(d) + ")"; });
```

remember update proyection on drag and/or zoom.

Comment: Thanks for the update... I think the problem I'm having now is that `my_coords` is not a set of features but simply a list of latitude/longitude pairs. I'm not sure how to proceed from here, but I'll look more into topojson.

Comment: can you post something more: data, code, jsFiddle, JSBin? so we can help

Comment: Thanks for offering to help: does this link work? http://plnkr.co/edit/DIJtCddCwfeNtRoxOR9P?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the update -- I have it working now, though I have to explicitly add a class to my path and translate the coordinates in a selection of this class according to the projection rotation on drag, as you said.